# How to show year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to group the item counts three years prior and three years after on certain date, but I was not able to break the item counts in three separate years.

```
SELECT
ITEM,
CASE WHEN DATE >='12/6/02' AND DATE <'12/6/05' AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN 'RICE PRIOR'
CASE WHEN DATE >='12/06/05' AND DATE <'12/6/08' AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN 'RICE POST'
END AS TYPE,
COUNT (QTY) AS RICE
FROM #TEMP

WHERE DATE >='12/6/02'
AND DATE <'12/6/08'
GROUP BY ITEM,
 CASE WHEN DATE >='12/6/02' AND DATE <'12/6/05' AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN 'RICE PRIOR'
CASE WHEN DATE >='12/06/05' AND DATE <'12/6/08' AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN 'RICE POST'
END
```

How can I break it down into three years? Running this script, my result shows:

```
Type,     Rice
Rice Prior 444
Rice Post  555
```

My desired output would be something like:

```
Year3, Year2, Year1  Year1, Year2, Year3
4      44     400     5      500    50
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data with expected result?

Comment: Just a small remark to start with. It is easier to use WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2012/06/02' AND '2015/06/05'
Maybe just GROUP BY YEAR(DATE) is enough to suit your needs

Comment: @Tom just a small note, between is inclusive, and his conditions are not, so to OP just be aware to test the date boundaries to make sure they are working as you want.

Comment: @Jeremy you are right.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @Tom, i added the Year(date) with the group by but the result shows for years instead of three years, which i wanted. Thanks

Comment: i am using SQL server

Comment: @ Madhivanan, I added some sample result. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should match your desired query using a pivot and date parameter so you don't have to hard code it all the dates and conditions.

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '12/6/2005'
SELECT
    ITEM,
    [-3] AS Year3,
    [-2] AS Year2,
    [-1] AS Year1,
    [1] AS Year1,
    [2] AS Year2,
    [3] AS Year3
FROM (
    SELECT
        ITEM,
        DATEDIFF(DD, @Date, [DATE]) / 365
            + CASE WHEN @Date < [DATE] THEN 1 ELSE -1 END  AS [YR],
        QTY
    FROM #TEMP
    ) T
    PIVOT (MAX(QTY) FOR [YR] IN ([-3], [-2], [-1], [1], [2], [3])) PVT
```

The above approach does not account for leap years. You can apply @JPW's approach of using `DATEADD` which is aware of leap years. You'll just need to be aware of the border scenarios of which is the first and last day of each region.  In this approach, the first match wins, so today's date would be in year "-1".

```
DECLARE @D DATE = '12/6/2005'
SELECT
    ITEM,
    [-3] AS Year3,
    [-2] AS Year2,
    [-1] AS Year1,
    [1] AS Year1,
    [2] AS Year2,
    [3] AS Year3
FROM (
    SELECT
        ITEM,
        CASE
            WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -3, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @D) THEN -3
            WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @D) THEN -2
            WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, -0, @D) THEN -1
            WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, +0, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, +1, @D) THEN 1
            WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, +1, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, +2, @D) THEN 2
            WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, +2, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, +3, @D) THEN 3
            ELSE NULL END AS [YR],
        QTY
    FROM #TEMP
    ) T
    PIVOT (MAX(QTY) FOR [YR] IN ([-3], [-2], [-1], [1], [2], [3])) PVT
```

Comment: That's a nice solution too. A bit cleaner that the conditional aggregations.

Comment: @Jason W. This is good stuff. However, when adding the three years together, the numbers dont match with the total. I was wondering if it is a leap year in 2008? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @joe 2008 was indeed a leap year as was 2004.

Comment: I just quickly came up with that to show you a PIVOT approach. You can make it more accurate by dividing by 365.25 or merge @JPW's approach for calculating the year offset into this PIVOT since DATEADD accounts for leap years.

Comment: Just updated answer to also show accounting for leap years.

Comment: Thanks Jason W. I changed MAX to SUM in the PIVOT. For some reason, when adding all the year together, it does not match with the total. I am still trouble shooting the issue.

Comment: If you can setup a basic SQL Fiddle reproducing the issue with actual sample data and the pivot query, then post that as another question on here, and you'd probably get 5 answers in 10 minutes :)

Comment: @Jason W, I was able to figure out the desired output that i was looking for. Thanks everyone again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample output I think a query like below might be what you want. You might have to tweak the date ranges to fit your needs but the general idea should be clear:

```
DECLARE @d date = '2005-07-27';
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
       ITEM
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -3, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @D) AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN QTY END) 'RICE PRIOR -3'
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @D) AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN QTY END) 'RICE PRIOR -2'
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, -0, @D) AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN QTY END) 'RICE PRIOR -1'
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, +0, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, +1, @D) AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN QTY END) 'RICE POST +1'
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, +1, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, +2, @D) AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN QTY END) 'RICE POST +2'
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, +2, @D) AND DATEADD(YEAR, +3, @D) AND ITEM ='RICE' THEN QTY END) 'RICE POST +3'
    FROM #TEMP
    WHERE DATE >='2002-05-12' AND DATE <'2008-06-12'
    GROUP BY ITEM
)

SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you can apply your count logic inside the select portion of PIVOT and then pivot the result set on years

```
SELECT ITEM, [2002] AS[Year-3],[2003] AS [Year-2], [2004] AS [Year-1],
[2005] AS [Year1],[2006] AS [Year2],[2007] AS [Year3]
FROM (
-- Your logic here
SELECT
ITEM,
YEAR(Date) as Y,
COUNT (quantity) AS RICE
FROM [dbo].[temp]
WHERE DATE >='12/6/01'
AND DATE <'12/6/08'
GROUP BY ITEM,YEAR(Date)
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(RICE)
    FOR Y IN ([2002], [2003], [2004], [2005],[2006],[2007])
)AS p
```

Sql fiddle link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa406/2

Comment: @ DhruvJoshi, Thanks for the quick script. I modified it accordingly but when adding the year together, the sum does not add up to the total three years combined. not sure why. Still trouble shooting....

Comment: @joe I hope this anomaly is not with Sql fiddle example. Please note that sql-fiddle has sum in the top logic part instead of count because I did not have much data to show meaningful count results. Please modify your logic according your needs. If this is not sql fiddle example that you were talking about, I suspect that where clause is what is filtering data out.